# Understanding weak and unowned reference in Swift under the hood

Tags: swift, weak-references, strong-references, unowned-references

I want fully understand what going inside weak and unowned referance in Swift. 
For this i read [MikeAsh](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2017-09-22-swift-4-weak-references.html) and got some questions.

What already known:

1. when there is no *weak* (and, i suppose, *unowned*) object reference, the strong reference counter is stored directly in the memory area of the object
2. when a *weak* link appears, the second word in the object memory is reused to reference the *side table*
3. *side table* has link to the object
4. *weak* link refers to this *side table*

And what i want to clearify:

1. What else *side table* store inside except link to the object and number of *strong* reference?
2. Is *unowned* reference link to the *side table* too? If not and *unowned* link refers to the object memory what about performance between *weak* and *unowned* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i found out.

1. *Unowned* link points to the object as well as *strong*.
2. *Unowned* link faster than *weak*.
3. *Side table* stores *strong* RC, *weak* RC, *unowned* RC, link to the object and some flags